# Dynamic Chart in Excel

Tags: excel, charts, offset, automatic-properties

```
Country      January    February    March   April   May June    July
USA             34        34          45     34      23
China           45        56          34     23      12
Japan           34        54          23     23      24
```

How can I show the last 3 months in the chart every time I update the data. Considering that column "Country" is fixed. Any workaround or easy formula to use in my "data selection" when creating a chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work perfectly.

**1. Re-arramge the data**

```
    Country    USA  China  Japan
    January    34    45     34
    February   34    56     54
    March      45    34     23
    April      34    23     23
    May        23    12     24
```

Like so, it will be easier to work with. Here we assume the data starts at cell A1.

**2. Create names in Name Manager (*ctr+F3* to open)**

```
    name:      refers to:

    months     =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1,0,-MIN(length,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1),1)
    length     3
    usa        =OFFSET(months,0,1)
    china      =OFFSET(months,0,2)
    japan      =OFFSET(months,0,3)
```

In *length*, you note the desired time-period you wish to show (in your case 3 months); this can also be done with a cell reference and a *COUNTA* if you wish to make it dynamic and account for all the new data.

**3. Create the chart**

- Click on blank cell and open the desired chart (I have done it with a
  2-D Clustered Column). //Note that the chart should be blank.
- Right-click on *Select Data* and click *Add* for *Legend Entries
  (Series)*. Here for Series Name, select whatever is desired (in your case USA China Japan). For Series Value add `=Sheet1!usa`
- Do this two more times for `=Sheet1!china` & `=Sheet1!japan`
- Finally for the *Axis Label* add `=Sheet1!months`

Click though OK and you should be all set!

Make sure you check out how the offset function works here: https://support.office.com/en-za/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66

Comment: Hi,Stelian. I have done this workaround but I got a very large set of data (I got 25 countries). Would it possible without arranging it differently as presented in your #1.

Comment: Hi Greth, the formula should work either way. Ignore step 1 and you're good to go.

Comment: Hi, do you have an email add? I hope you could help me out with my file.

Comment: I do, but it does not show up. Anyway, here it is: s.m.nenkov@gmail.com